# Quotes in Node.js spawn arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, tar, spawn

I'm using double quotes in Node.js `spawn` arguments because they can potentially contain spaces:

```
const excludes = ['/foo/bar', '/foo/baz', '/foo/bar baz'];
const tar = spawn('tar', [
  '--create', '--gzip',
  // '--exclude="/foo/bar"', '--exclude="/foo/baz"', '--exclude="/foo/bar baz"'
  ...excludes.map(exclude => `--exclude="${exclude}"`),
  '/foo'
], { stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', 'inherit'] });
```

For some reason, `tar` ignores `--exclude` arguments that are supplied this way. The result is same with `spawn` being `require('child_process').spawn` and `require('cross-spawn')`.

`--exclude` works as expected when there are no double quotes for paths that don't require them.

And the same thing works as expected from shell, even with double quotes:

```
tar --create --gzip --exclude="/foo/bar" --exclude="/foo/baz" /foo > ./foo.tgz
```

I'm not sure what's going on there and how `spawn` can be debugged to check if it does some odd escaping for double quotes.

Comment: I can't read C language, but you can provide `{ shell: true }` as the option to let shell to handle it. It also provides normalization for quotes.

Answer (score 21):

This is an issue in quote type precedence. Double-quotes take precedence over single-quotes, so the spawn call breaks down.

The system shell will strip off quotes around parameters, so the program gets the unquoted value at the end. Spawning a process bypasses this step as it bypasses the shell, so the program gets those literal quotes as part of the parameter and doesn't know how to handle them appropriately.

There are two real options to resolve this that I'm aware of:

1. It's counter-intuitive, but switching the quote types around should resolve this issue. Switch your above code to:

   ```
   const tar = spawn("tar", [
     "--create", "--gzip",
     "--exclude='/foo/bar'", "--exclude='/foo/baz'", "/foo"
   ], { stdio: ["ignore", "pipe", "inherit"] });
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can use `{ shell: true }` and use your current formatting. This will pass the spawn request through the shell, so the parsing step that's currently being skipped will occur. See more about this [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/v7.2.1/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows).

   ```
   const tar = spawn('tar', [
     '--create', '--gzip',
     '--exclude="/foo/bar"', '--exclude="/foo/baz"', '/foo'
   ], { stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', 'inherit'], shell: true });
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried single quotes, they give a similar result. And shell:true option works for me indeed. Still not sure what happens with args when `tar` is called without it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had the same issue with `rsync --exclude '.git' [...]`. `shell:true` is the solution.

Comment: @GabrielGlenn, please mind the vulnerabilities that come from using `shell:true`, you should sanitize the arguments see this article https://developer.ibm.com/articles/avoiding-arbitrary-code-execution-vulnerabilities-when-using-nodejs-child-process-apis/

Answer (score 6):

If I understand what you're asking, you just want to keep the default shell behavior of stripping the quotes and passing the argument as a single argument even if it has spaces.

In that case, you can do:

```
spawn(exe, args, { windowsVerbatimArguments: true });
```

See [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options):

> `windowsVerbatimArguments` `<boolean>` No quoting or escaping of arguments is done on Windows. Ignored on Unix. This is set to `true` automatically when `shell` is specified and is CMD. **Default:** `false`.

Answer (score 5):

You should understand how the shell handles spaces and quotation marks. I say "the shell" - there are different shells and I don't know the differences between them, so it's possible that what I'm about to write won't apply to you. Someone feel free to edit this so it's more precise.

There are all sorts of syntactic complications you can include in a shell command: piped commands, input and output files, interpolated variables, interpolated commands, environment variables, and at least 4 (yes, four) different ways of quoting strings. But for the purposes of this question, let's just say that a shell command is a command name followed by a (possibly empty) list of string arguments. The command name could be a built-in command (`cd`, `ls`, `sudo`, etc), or it could be an executable file. Or, to put it another way, a shell command is a list of one or more strings (including the first string, which tells the shell what kind of command it is).

Because of the complications mentioned above, several characters are special characters. Which means you might need to escape them using quotation marks. However, quotation marks introduce a lot of redundancy into the language. For example, the following commands are equivalent:

```
tar --create --exclude=/foo/bar /foo
tar --create --exclude='/foo/bar' /foo
tar --create --exclude="/foo/bar" /foo
tar --create '--exclude=/foo/bar' /foo
tar --create "--exclude=/foo/bar" /foo
```

In each case, the command is to run the executable `tar` with the argument list `--create`, `--exclude=/foo/bar`, `/foo`.

Note the behaviour of quotation marks, which differs from all other languages I know of. In most languages, a string literal is completely enclosed by a pair of quotation marks - that's how the compiler/interpreter knows where they start and end. But in shell commands, whitespace is what tells the shell where one argument ends and the next one begins. (Quoted/escaped whitespace doesn't count.) The only purpose of quotation marks is to change the way some characters are treated. Shell commands are very flexible about this, so the following commands are also equivalent to the ones above:

```
tar -"-"create --exc'lude=/fo'o/bar /foo
tar --cr'eate' --exclude"="/foo"/bar" /foo
```

And when I say these commands are equivalent, I mean the `tar` executable cannot know which one has been invoked. That is, it is impossible to write an executable file `mycommand` such that the commands `mycommand foo` and `mycommand "foo"` write different output to STDOUT or STDERR, or return different exit codes, or otherwise behave differently.

However, when running shell commands from nodejs, you don't need to use the shell features for piping, streaming to/from files, interpolating variables, etc, because javascript can handle all that stuff if you want. So when you supply the arguments to `spawn`, it bypasses those shell features; it doesn't do anything with shell special characters. You just supply the arguments directly. So in the following example, one of the arguments will be `--exclude=/foo/bar baz`, which will cause `tar` to ignore the file/directory called `bar baz` in the `/foo` directory:

```
const tar = spawn('tar', [
  '--create', '--gzip',
  '--exclude=/foo/bar', '--exclude=/foo/baz', '--exclude=/foo/bar baz',
  '/foo'
], { stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', 'inherit'] });
```

(Although obviously, if you're using javascript string literals, you might need to escape some characters at the javascript level.)

I don't like either of joshuhn's answers. (1) didn't even work for me, and I'm surprised it worked for him - if it did then I view it as a bug in nodejs (or possibly in `tar`). (I'm running nodejs v6.9.5 in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, with GNU tar v1.28.) As for (2), it means unnecessarily introducing all the complexities of shell string processing into your javascript code. As [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v6.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) says:

> Note: If the `shell` option is enabled, do not pass unsanitised user input to this function. Any input containing shell metacharacters may be used to trigger arbitrary command execution.

I for one don't know all the intricacies of shell escaping, so I would not risk running `spawn` with the `shell` option with untrusted input.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. However, it's unclear what solution you are suggesting. I can't supply the arguments directly because they can potentially contain whitespaces. I updated the question to show that they really can.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with spaces. In a shell command, if you want literal spaces you have to use quotation marks because a space without quotes means it's the end of the argument. But in `spawn`, the arguments have already been split up; there's no need to state which spaces are to be treated as literal because they all are. I've updated the answer to include a space in one of the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The `shell` option is risky because you might type non portable commands. For example `NODE_ENV=production webpack` would only work on Linux, but fail on Windows (env setting)

It would be best to fully split compound arguments and let the system do the magic. For example:

```bash
const tar = spawn('tar', [
  '--create', '--gzip',
  '--exclude', "/foo/don't bar"
]);
```